# R - Transforming data in dataframe from one time scale to another

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I currently have two dataframes, each with a date column and then several columns of numeric data. The first dataframe, "daily", has data that is approximately but not exactly daily in periodicity while the second dataframe, "weekly", has data that is approximately but not exactly weekly in periodicity. What I would like to accomplish is to replace the "weekly" dataframe with one that has the same dates as "daily" and backfills data with the previous value for any missing values. I know that I can use na.locf from the zoo package to backfill  the data but I am unsure as to how I can effectively introduce the dates from the "daily" dataframe. Perhaps some variation of a merge or join?

Sample Data:

```
daily<-data.frame(
    date1=rep(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-09-10"), by="1 day"), each=1),
    value1=runif(254),
    value2=rnorm(254), 
    value3=rpois(254,10)
)

weekly<-data.frame(
    date2=rep(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-09-10"), by="1 week"), each=1),
    value4=runif(37),
    value5=rnorm(37), 
    value6=rpois(37,10)
)

"result" should have date1 and then value4, value5, and value6 as columns and then na.locf can be used to backfill any missing data.
```

Comment: sure, sounds plausible.  can you include some data? see `?dput`.  Some dummy data would also work.

Comment: @AndrewMacDonald Added dummy data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `zoo` and also `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

daily %>%
   left_join(weekly %>% 
               select(date1 = date2,value4:value6)) %>%
   mutate_each(funs(na.locf),value4:value6) %>%
   head  # obviously don't keep this last function! ;)
Joining by: "date1"
       date1     value1     value2 value3    value4   value5 value6
1 2000-01-01 0.01670715 -0.6526126      9 0.3648553 0.775517      8
2 2000-01-02 0.21580455 -0.7702071      9 0.3648553 0.775517      8
3 2000-01-03 0.16307286  1.1770171      9 0.3648553 0.775517      8
4 2000-01-04 0.91464458  1.5960920      9 0.3648553 0.775517      8
5 2000-01-05 0.13975950  1.4407381     13 0.3648553 0.775517      8
6 2000-01-06 0.75104455 -0.5890481     11 0.3648553 0.775517      8
```

Note the use of `select` to rename the date column so that it is the same in both datsets.

Comment: Works very well. Thank you. What is the %>% though?

Comment: What would I have to change in your code to only have value4,value5, and value6 in the resultant dataframe. In other words, only the data columns from weekly.

Comment: `%>%` is a pipe operator, which is used in `dplyr` to move the output of one function into another. It was originally in package `magrittr`.  See [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html)

Comment: You mean you want to kill the columns `value1` to `value3` without removing duplicated rows?  There's lots of ways; the `dplyr` method would be to replace `head` at the end with `select(date1,value4:value6)`

Comment: Thank you and one more thing. Say I don't know what the names of value4:value6 are. Is there anyway to do the same thing by column number or just selecting all of the columns in weekly

Comment: Sure, you could assign the result of the code above to an object, say `result` and then use `result[names(weekly)]`.  See also ?select in `dplyr`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56266/discussion-between-user2844947-and-andrewmacdonald).

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, using `data.table`'s `roll` feature:

```
require(data.table) ## >= 1.9.2
setkey(setDT(daily), date1)
setkey(setDT(weekly), date2)
ans <- weekly[daily, roll=TRUE]
```

> `setDT`           - converts data.frame to data.table by reference (no copy)
>   `setkey`          - sorts the data.table by that column (required for join)
>   `x[i, roll=TRUE]` - performs a rolling join

Comment: Good, concise answer but I want to keep my data as a dataframe rather than as a data table.